# Javascript ES6 code optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to convert our current jQuery codes into ES6 for a slider.
Below is the current jQuery code:

```
$('.slider-nav a').click(function (event) {
        $('.slider-nav a').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('.slider-content').not($(this).data('target')).removeClass('current');
        $($(this).data('target')).addClass('current');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

And here is my updated javascript code

```
    let contentSlidersNavs = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-nav a');

    if (contentSlidersNavs.length) {
        for (let current_item of contentSlidersNavs) {
            current_item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                let target_element = event.target || event.srcElement;                
                for(let current_item of contentSlidersNavs){
                    if(current_item !== target_element){
                        current_item.classList.remove('current');
                    }
                }
                current_item.classList.add('current');
                let current_content_id = current_item.dataset.target;
                let slider_contents = document.querySelectorAll(`.slider-content:not(${current_content_id})`);
                for(let current_content of slider_contents){
                    current_content.classList.remove('current');
                }
                document.querySelector(`.slider-content${current_content_id}`).classList.add('current');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
}
```

As you can see, my new code becomes three times larger than the previous jQuery code and look like more complex.

For example, the following jQuery line:

```
 $('.slider-nav a').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
```

Becomes this ES6 block:

```
let target_element = event.target || event.srcElement;                
            for(let current_item of contentSlidersNavs){
                if(current_item !== target_element){
                    current_item.classList.remove('current');
                }
            }
```

So, I would like to ask your suggestion, is there any way I can optimize my codes in terms of performance or make the code cleaner?

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/afhy6xhj/) to play around.

Thank you!

Comment: One (inconsequentially minor) tidy-up you could make is the outermost `if`: a `for..of` loop is quite happy if you provide an empty set.

Comment: Arr yes!. It was my habit to avoid the empty set in different pages. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few pointers:

- You don't need to attach an event handler to every anchor. Attach one to the parent tag, let the event bubble up, and then use the `target` variable you made earlier to determine which one was clicked.
- You could really benefit from ES6 arrow functions.
- Use the `forEach` method on `NodeList`s.  <del>and forego the `:not` logic entirely since you already are calling `.classList.add('current')` later on for the element you want to be current.</del> (Edit: OP had a good reason to use `not`; it was required due to an animation that would flash otherwise.)
- You're probably not [supporting IE 6-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Compatibility_notes), so just go with `event.target` and don't worry about `event.srcElement`.
- Lift as many DOM queries as possible out of your event handler.

**Edit:** You can actually combine `.slider-nav a` and `.slider-content` into one big DOM query, and remove the `current` class from them all at once.

### Option 1: I prefer not to have the links scroll to each paragraph

```js
let sliderNavsAndContents = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-nav a, .slider-content')

document.querySelector('.slider-nav').addEventListener('click', event => {

  let target = document.querySelector(event.target.getAttribute('data-target'))
  sliderNavsAndContents.forEach(e => 
    e.classList[e === event.target || e === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('current')
  )
  
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="#" data-target="#content1">Link to first paragraph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="#content2">Link to second pargraph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="#content3">Link to third pargraph</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="viewport">
  <div id="content1" class="slider-content current">
    <h3>Vestibulum ante ipsum</h3>
    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="slider-content">
    <h3>Nulla porttitor accumsan</h3>
    <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="slider-content">
    <h3>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget</h3>
    <p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices .</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Option 2: I might like having the links scroll to each paragraph

- Notice the changes to the HTML here. No more `data-target` attribute; the `id` of the target is embedded into the `href` and you can get it via the anchor's `hash` property.

```js
let sliderNavsAndContents = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-nav a, .slider-content')

document.querySelector('.slider-nav').addEventListener('click', event => {

  let target = document.querySelector(event.target.hash)
  sliderNavsAndContents.forEach(e => 
    e.classList[e === event.target || e === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('current')
  )

})
```

```css
.current{
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="#content1">Link to first paragraph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content2">Link to second pargraph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content3">Link to third pargraph</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="viewport">
  <div id="content1" class="slider-content current">
    <h3>Vestibulum ante ipsum</h3>
    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="slider-content">
    <h3>Nulla porttitor accumsan</h3>
    <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="slider-content">
    <h3>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget</h3>
    <p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices .</p>
    <div><a class="readmore" href="#'">READ MORE</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect one. Unfortunately, I still have to stick with :not logic because there is an animation for adding 'current' class to the slider content. So, it keeps blinking due to removing and re-adding when we click the same nav. But your answer is perfect for the question that I asked. Thanks Gyre. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I've added the "not" logic back into the first example. Let me know if that does it.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing a demonstration in the beauty of jQuery; shorter, leaner code. The penalty is the increased loading time and slightly slower performance.

To answer your question, no, there's not really any way to optimise the 'not' logic you have. Whichever way you do it, you'll need a loop.

You could potentially use the `:not` selector with `querySelectorAll()`, but that relies on turning the `target_element` object in to a valid selector string.

Comment: I see. I will also think about your advice for :not selector with querySelectorAll(). Thank you Rory!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.